# Concrete computation of pullback of the $D$-module $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, geometric-representation-theory

I have some problems in calculating some example explicitly. Consider
$$ \{0\} \overset{i}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{C} \overset{j}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{C}^*.$$
Then $Rj_+\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] = \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] = D_\mathbb{C}/\partial_ttD_\mathbb{C}$.
Then you can calculate $Li^*\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ by
$$D_{\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}}\otimes^L_{i^{-1}D_{\mathbb{C}}}i^{-1}\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]=\mathbb{C}[\partial_t]\overset{\text{right multiplication }\partial_tt}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{C}[\partial_t].$$
Note that $\partial_tt$ maps $\partial_t^n$ to $(n+1)\partial_t^n$, which implies that $D_{\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}}\otimes^L_{i^{-1}D_{\mathbb{C}}}i^{-1}\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]=0$.

However, by Riemann-Hilbert corrspondence, we can consider $i^{-1}Rj_*\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}^*}$, which are $\mathbb{C}$ in cohomology degree $0$ and $1$, contradicts the calculation above. But I do not know where is the thing going wrong.

Comment: In Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, the counterpart of $i^{-1}$ should be $Li^*$ twisted by the Verdier dual.  After doing that, the calculations on both sides match.

Comment: @XiaowenHu But $Li^*$ is already zero. I do not think that a zero object can become non zero after twisting.

Comment: @XiaowenHu I see. In the Riemann-Hilbert, I should first twist $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ by Verdier dual, then apply $Li^*$. But then the differential map of the pullback complex should be right multiplication by $t\partial_t$. This gives the correct computation! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for evoking this good example of Riemann-Hilbert correspondence.